# How to validate the Digg Digg WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the Digg Digg WordPress plugin on my blog. It's giving me 16 w3c validation error's.

Kindly help me out to remove these errors. (Twitter, FaceBook and Google+ integeration plugin)

Error example:

```
Line 652, Column 168: there is no attribute "data-url"

…class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://blog.mysite.com/" data-cou…
```

Second error:

```
Error Line 652, Column 211: there is no attribute "data-count"

…://blog.mysite.com/" data-count="vertical" data-text="Email…
```

Comment: Are you validating your page using html5 mode?

Comment: i am using XHTML 1.0 Transitional mode

Comment: You'll need html5 for this to validate.

Comment: but wordpress has xhtml doctype,what should i do in this case now

Comment: @user696734 — Wordpress does not, the template you are using does. You can edit Wordpress templates.

Answer (score 0):

Either.

1. Change your markup language to one that supports `data-` attributes (i.e. HTML 5) *or*
2. Rewrite the plugin (including the JavaScript it uses) to put the data elsewhere. (It would be valid, albeit very ugly, in the class attribute. Another option would be to move it into an object literal in a `<script>` element).

Comment: i searched for it and find some thing,i edit the plugin for example  const BASEURL ="<script type=\"text/javascript\"> /*<![CDATA[*/
 document.write('<a href=\"http://twitter.com/share\" class=\"twitter-share-button\" data-url=\"VOTE_URL\" data-count=\"VOTE_BUTTON_DESIGN\" data-text=\"VOTE_TITLE\" data-via=\"VOTE_SOURCE\" ></a>');
   /*]]>*/</script>
 <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\"></script>";

Comment: can you tell me please.is it possible with out doctype changing

Comment: @user696734 — See option 2. I'm not going to do that for you though, it sounds like it will be a largish piece of work that is only going to be useful to a narrow audience.